# Show a geom as a separate legend in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot with two `geoms` that I want to separate in the `legend`

The data:

```
   df <- structure(list(sexo = c("Hombres", "Mujeres", "Ambos sexos", 
                        "Hombres", "Mujeres", "Ambos sexos", "Hombres", "Mujeres", "Ambos sexos", 
                        "Hombres", "Mujeres", "Ambos sexos", "Hombres", "Mujeres", "Ambos sexos"),
                     ing_t_p = c(615365.502213837, 423714.908007251, 535311.193293098, 
               627821.976453452, 433415.145738095, 546208.601052767, 664363.627171407, 
               467060.109828569, 581086.381783187, 685007.895112625, 499376.45299215, 
               606399.207890318, 704273.922502823, 506650.544840556, 620528.397683238), 
                     se = c(10529.5553778887, 7210.55027509547, 7718.92697284312, 
          11877.7721047204, 7291.10677673023, 8523.46596771153, 11819.5502743658, 
          7851.50601614168, 8599.97620004388, 14684.6464451213, 9287.24516124394, 
          10906.4036899172, 14883.8815328947, 8761.69267167345, 10604.2123276546), 
                      anio = c(2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2017, 2017, 2017, 
            2018, 2018, 2018, 2019, 2019, 2019), 
                      brecha = c(-0.31144188862896, -0.31144188862896, -0.31144188862896, -0.309652796503805, 
                 -0.309652796503805, -0.309652796503805, -0.296981215216246, -0.296981215216246, -0.296981215216246, -0.270991682643241, -0.270991682643241, -0.270991682643241, 
              -0.280605842908339, -0.280605842908339, -0.280605842908339)), 
             row.names = c(NA, -15L), class = "data.frame")
```

The plot:

```
ggplot(df, aes(anio, ing_t_p/1000, fill = factor(sexo, levels = c("Mujeres", "Ambos sexos", "Hombres")))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  geom_point(aes(anio, brecha*-1000), size = 5, colour = "#76A7EF") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

The desired legend:

[image]

I've tried toying around with `theme()` arguments and reviewed the answer [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43187410/how-can-i-separate-legends-in-ggplot2-so-they-dont-overlap) but I can't seem to make it work. Any help would be gratly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```r
ggplot(df) +
  geom_bar(aes(anio, ing_t_p/1000, 
               fill = factor(sexo, levels = c("Mujeres", "Ambos sexos", "Hombres"))), 
           position="dodge", stat="identity") +
  geom_point(aes(anio, brecha*-1000, color = "BRECHA"), size = 5) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = c("red", "blue", "orange")) + 
  scale_color_manual("label", values = "#76A7EF") +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank(), 
        legend.position = "bottom")
```

Comment: Get `aesthetics` separate for each `geom`, gotcha. Thanks!